# R:Correlation-Plot - Not able to render correlation-plot across tables in Power BI desktop app

Tags: r, powerbi

I have installed R in power-bi desktop application which automatically imports various visualization charts in power-bi app. Among them, I want to use correlation-plot but its rendering blank chart.

Detailed description is given below:

Problem Statement: I want to render correlation-plot among actual_qty(from table d_masters) and cp, cpk(from table m_data), Refer inline images for better understanding (Blurred out some part of sensitive data in images).

Database used: Azure SQL

Query Mode: Direct query

Relationships among SQL tables are shown below:
[image]

I am able to render correlation-plot using single table(correlation between cp and cpk from table 'm_data'). Graph and exported data from correlation plot are given below:
[image]

[image]

When I select multiple tables which have many to many relationships based on foreign-key then it won't render correlation-plot. Also if I export correlation-plot data then it gives valid data but doesn't render correlation-plot.
[image]

[image]

Please guide me what else I need to do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check you table relation is correct .
1) one to many 
2) many to many

Comment: Relationships are correct because it is showing data in exported table format but not in correlation-plot.